# Is there any C# 3D Graphics Library that can help me calculating 2D positions of 3D object in space?

Tags: 3d, 2d, game-engine, rendering-engine

My goal is that I put some objects in a 3D space and call Render(),then this library could tell me the rendering position on 2d screen of each object.

Or like a 3d game engine,but I want to take over the rendering part,I want to render these objects myself.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about XNAMath? That should be good enough to satisfy all your needs. In fact it is now a part of DirectX SDK.

Edit: If you want some practical insight into geometry for computer graphics, here's a comprehensive [book](http://books.google.am/books?id=YmQy799flPkC&printsec=frontcover&hl=hy&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) that covers all the topics.
And no matter what graphics you're designing, a game, cg demo or anything, math is the same everywhere.

Comment: Can I use this library without XNA Framework?My software is not a game.Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can use the library apart from XNA Framework. Although it's called XNAMath, it's not a part of XNA and is written in C++. Also, it uses latest SIMD optimizations so I guess it's the most efficient math library available.

Answer (score 0):

Any library supporting matrix operations may be helpful but I recommend you to use Managed DirectX. It has many utility functions especially for 3D graphics.

After you select a library, make a proper view matrix and a projection matrix using that. Multiply the two matrices into a matrix, and then multiply the matrix with a position in 3D(the center of a object or some vertex). The result vecter will point the position of the object in 2D screen. This is a standard pipeline of 3D graphics, you can find many references using the keyword.

Comment: My software is not a game,so can I just use matrix operations?Or if there have any articles can tell me the algorithm.Thanks.